# Virtual Keyboard with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keypress, melonjs

I have a div that operates as a button. Once the button is clicked, I want it to simulate the pressing of a key. Elsewhere on Stackoverflow, people have suggested using `jQuery.Event("keydown");` but the suggestions all use a `.trigger()` bound to the button as opposed to `.click`.  So, my example code looks like this:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keydown");
press.which = 69; // # The 'e' key code value
press.keyCode = 69;

$('#btn').click( function() {
    $('#testInput').focus();
    $(this).trigger(press);
    console.info(press);
});
```

I've set up a dummy example at JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ruzel/WsAbS/

Eventually, rather than have the keypress fill in a form element, I just want to register the event as a keypress to the document so that a MelonJS game can have it.

UPDATE: It looks like triggering a keypress with anything other than the keyboard is likely to be ignored by the browser for security reasons. For updating a text input, this very nice Jquery plugin will do the trick: http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/

As for anyone who comes here looking for the solution in the MelonJS case, it's best to use MelonJS's me.input object, like so:

```
$('#btn').mousedown(function() {
    me.input.triggerKeyEvent(me.input.KEY.E, true);
});

$('#btn').mouseup(function() {
    me.input.triggerKeyEvent(me.input.KEY.E, false);
});
```

Comment: So what's your question? If you want to trigger it on the `document`, just use that instead of `this`. `$(document).trigger(press);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you need for MelonJS, but I think you're looking for `$('#testInput').trigger(press);` instead of `$(this).trigger(press);`. This won't actually insert any text into the textbox, but it will simulate the 69 keycode being pressed in that textbox. And it will bubble up to `document` automatically (the nature of `.trigger`) - http://jsfiddle.net/WsAbS/5/

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Yes, like I said in my update above, it looks like you can't send a keypress to an input that doesn't come from the actual keyboard doe security reasons.  As for MelonJS, I addressed that in the update above as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but even though this **is triggering the event correctly**, it doesn't fill the input with the character.

I've modified the code to show that the document is indeed receiving keypress events when we say `$(document).trigger(p)`

Try it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/WsAbS/3/

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keydown");
press.which = 69; // # Some key code value
press.keyCode = 69;
press.target = $('#testInput');


$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    alert(event.keyCode);
});

$('#btn').click( function() {
    $(document).trigger(press);
});
```

I believe this should be good enough for your end goal of a MelonJS game picking up keypresses.

Comment: But this is unnecessary. Triggering the event on `$(this)` (or anything in `document`) causes the event to bubble up to `document` and it will be caught by it anyways.

Comment: OK, but my point was to create a simple proof that this is triggering the keydown event.  If we're really going to get into `this` vs `document`, why not just say `document` in the first place if that's where we want it to bubble up to? It's clearer and it saves the computer time.

Comment: What you said is true, but it doesn't simulate a keydown event for the textbox. In your example, it doesn't bubble up the DOM chain like a normal keydown event (like physically pressing a key on your keyboard). How do you know there aren't other elements listening for this event that require it have the correct origination? I think the OP was triggering it on the wrong element anyways - `this` refers to the pseudo button, but they should trigger it on the `input` element. It seems like accuracy is more important than "saving the computer time", but then again I don't know what MelonJS needs.

Comment: I thought that initially (that OP was triggering on wrong element), too, but when I changed it to `$('#testInput').trigger(press);` in the JSFiddle, it still didn't work.  You're right that it might need to bubble up from a specific element, but I figured OP could change this simple example to his specific needs.

Comment: @crazedgremlin—I just assumed here that if an input element could receive a keypress event from another DOM object, then I could just as easily send that event to the MelonJS UI. I'm not sure that's even true at this point. I implemented your code to check that the event occurs and your code does alert the key press, but MelonJS (as well as text inputs) aren't reacting to it. If you want to get a better picture of the MelonJS situation, that code is here: http://www.russellbits.com/labs/bloop/ipad.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a virtual keyboard (As the title suggests) you can use [this](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/) one.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but kudos for the link. I'm certain that will come in handy in the future.